# Downcasting in Swift with as and as?

Tags: cocoa, swift, downcast

What's the difference between these two code snippets:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId") as UITableViewCell?
// vs
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId") as? UITableViewCell
```

Isn't the result exactly the same?

Comment: `as UITableViewCell?` results in compile error in Swift 2 `AnyObject? is not convertible to UITableViewCell?`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In that code there's no difference, in both cases it evaluates to `UITableViewCell?`

The real difference is:

- in the first case a downcast to `UITableViewCell?` is expected to always succeed (even if it's nil), so if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns something that's not an instance of `UITableViewCell` (or an instance of a class inherited from it), it fails at runtime. The expression returns an optional `UITableViewCell?`
- in the second case the cast is optional: if the object returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is neither an instance of `UITableViewCell` nor an instance of a subclass, the downcast gracefully evaluates to nil (hence with no runtime error).

Of course `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a `UITableViewCell`, that's why there's no difference in your code. But in other contexts the difference may exist and you have to take care of that to prevent runtime errors

Answer (score 7):

Main difference between `as` and `as?` is that `as` is forced cast and will crash if unsuccessful. `as?` will return optional value containing value if cast was successful and `nil` if unsuccessful.

Comment: Does this mean that `as` and `as!` are the same?

Comment: @BR41N-FCK This has changed a bit, in Swift 2.0 `as` is only valid if there is no chance of failure (you will get compile time error if you use it when not allowed). `as!` is called forced casting and will crash if cast is not possible at runtime.

Comment: Is there a comparison of the three to get a better grasp of the nuances between them?

Comment: @BR41N-FCK `as` - available only if cast cannot fail. `as?` - optional cast (result is nil if cast is not possible), result is optional type. `as!` - forced cast, crash if cast is not possible.

Comment: If the case is such as what you've just described, is there any point for `as!` to exist? I mean if the cast can fail and you can deal with failure and go on `as?` seems the thing to go for, and if you can't allow any failure and it has to work then `as` seems applicable. And so why use `as!` especially considering the fact it can cause a run-time error and piss off the user.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between, `as` and `as?`

- `as? UITableViewCell` means when you don't know what you're `downcasting`, you are assuming that as a `UITableViewCell`, but it might me `Integer` or `Float` or `Array` or `Dictionary`.
- `as UITableViewCell?` means it's an `Optional Value`, it may either contain a `UITableViewCell` or `Nil` value.